# Error: Index out of Range UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating an app where it uses custom cells. I also have these `UITextView`'s where if you input a word, that word should then go to one of the four labels I created in the custom cell. I am still coding it however I got an error saying "Error: Index Out of Range".

Here is the code, and I also commented where it is giving that error

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

        cell.lbl.text = todolist[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl2.text = todolist2[indexPath.row] // This is the error code
        cell.lbl3.text = todolist3[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbl4.text = todolist4[indexPath.row]

        return cell   
}
```

Here is where I append my texts

```
@IBAction func ClickedforSelection(sender: AnyObject) {

    todolist.append(txt.text!)
    todolist2.append(txt1.text!)
    todolist3.append(txt2.text!)
    todolist4.append(txt3.text!)

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    txt.text = ""
    txt1.text = ""
    txt2.text = ""
    txt3.text = ""


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist, forKey: "list")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist2, forKey: "list2")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist3, forKey: "list3")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist4, forKey: "list4")
```

Here is my NumberofRowsInSection

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{


        return todolist.count

}
```

I have a conjecture that it may be the reuse of `indexPath.row`. Any solution?

Comment: Post other DataSource methods and how you append the text will be helpful.

Comment: Sure, please check the edit

Comment: Don't see any problem so far. Probably you could set breakpoint at each time when you try to set cell.lbl*.text.

Comment: It sill gives me "Error: Index out of Range" at cell.lbl2.text

Comment: Should I change the multiple IndexPath.rows to something else?

Comment: You can figure out the issue, just for the time being hard code the numberOfRowsInSection to 1

Comment: Do all of your todolist have the same length for always? Looks like you are assuming they all share the same length.

Comment: What do you mean by length, as in the dimensions of the actual label?

Comment: length: the count of your array

Comment: You are showing the appends, which are made equally for each array. So I suppose the problem is in the initial state of the array. Eg. You read it from `NSDefaults` and they already have different count of elements there. Or you use append elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If numberOfRowsInSection is returning todolist.count, you are accessing todolist2 in your cell.  If todolist has 2 items and todolist2 has 1 item, it will do this because you are trying to access an item in a list that doesn't exist.  Put a breakpoint at the first call of cell.lbl.text and check each array (todolist, todolist1, etc...).   You should see that todolist2 does not have have a record at whatever "row" it's calling.  If that is the case, you should just test it prior to calling it.  (verify todolist2.count has enough items in it - or better yet, change the code to not have 4 arrays tracking 1 row (convert to a struct of some type with all 4 values, or something similar).

First, change the following code by commenting out lines:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

        cell.lbl.text = todolist[indexPath.row]
   //     cell.lbl2.text = todolist2[indexPath.row] // This is the error code
   //     cell.lbl3.text = todolist3[indexPath.row]
   //     cell.lbl4.text = todolist4[indexPath.row]

        return cell   
}
```

And test to verify existing code (should work but of course it will not update the labels.)
Then add code to print the number of items in each array:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

        cell.lbl.text = todolist[indexPath.row]
   //     cell.lbl2.text = todolist2[indexPath.row] // This is the error code
   //     cell.lbl3.text = todolist3[indexPath.row]
   //     cell.lbl4.text = todolist4[indexPath.row]

  print("Row: \(indexPath.row)")
  print("List 1: \(todolist.count)")  //this will print to the console
  print("List 2: \(todolist2.count)")
  print("List 3: \(todolist3.count)")
  print("List 4: \(todolist4.count)")

        return cell   
}
```

What you will likely see is that they don't have the same number of items, and as soon as it his a "row" that is equal to or greater than the number of items, it will break.  Remember that Row's start at Zero, while count starts at 1.

If this is what you find, then there is problem something wrong with the code where you are adding the values to the todolist arrays.  If you want to see how to convert that to a struct, I can post that for you.

**Converting to struct**

The code that is executing when something is clicked:

```
@IBAction func ClickedforSelection(sender: AnyObject) {
```

shows that a value is written to each of the 4 todolists every time. While I don't have the full requirements, if this is what you want to do, then you *could* implement a struct.  Put this code in it's own ToDoList.swift file (ideally):

```
struct ToDoListItem {
    var listItem: String?
    var list1Item: String?
    var list2Item: String?
    var list3Item: String?
}
```

Then replace where you define your todolislt arrays (all 4 of them) with a single:

```
var listItems = [ToDoListItem]()  //creates an array of ToDoListItems and initializes it with no values
```

Then in the ClickedForSelection function, change it to:

```
let listItem = ToDoListItem(listItem: txt.text, list1Item: txt1.text, list2Item: txt2.text, list3Item: txt3.text) 
listItems.append(listItem)  //add it to your array

//todolist.append(txt.text!)
//todolist2.append(txt1.text!)
//todolist3.append(txt2.text!)
//todolist4.append(txt3.text!)

self.view.endEditing(true)
txt.text = ""
txt1.text = ""
txt2.text = ""
txt3.text = ""

//  This routine will need to be updated.  Leaving that for you to figure out :)
//    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist, forKey: "list")
//  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist2, forKey: "list2")
//    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist3, forKey: "list3")
//    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(todolist4, forKey: "list4")
```

...then numberOfRowsInSection changes to:

```
return listItems.count
```

...then cellForRowAtIndexPath changes to:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

    let listItem = listItems[indexPath.row]

    cell.lbl.text = listItem.listItem ?? ""  // Since listItems.listItem is an optional value, ?? unwraps it safely.  If it is nill, it uses "" instead
    cell.lbl2.text = listItem.list1Item ?? ""
    cell.lbl3.text = listItem.list2Item ?? ""
    cell.lbl4.text = listItem.list3Item ?? ""

    return cell
```

Again...I would strongly consider how you are storing a value for a todolist for all 4 lists every time (if it is a todo list app, it seems like this may not be ideal?)

Comment: Todolist as well as todolist2 have 1 item. I have a feeling that I need to change the "IndexPath.row" part to something else. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Add code to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to print `indexPath.row`, `todoList.count` and `todoList2.count`. It should give you a clue. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for each displayed row, so you must capture the call that actually fails...

Comment: Can you type what exactly I should do?

Comment: Yes I see now. Can you convert it to a struct for me, I would love if you could.

Comment: Can you please post a struct